# How to add ssh key in mac os?

Tags: macos, git, ssh, repository

I have an ssh key name.ppk I want to add by mac terminal to be able to clone from Git repository because when I am cloning from the repository it give me

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below step:

**Step1:** open terminal and paste below cmd with your email id which is being used in github or bitbucket or any other hosting service which you are using.

```
  ssh-keygen
```

**Step2**: You will get: **Generating public/private ssh key pair.** no need to type anything just press enter.

**Step3**: You will get **Enter file in which to save the key
(/Users/abhishekupadhyay/.ssh/id_rsa):**
Again don't do anything just press enter.

**Step4**: You will get **Your public key has been saved in /Users/abhishekupadhyay/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**

**Step5**: **The key fingerprint is:**
SHA256:0WHGzcQwaT4SabOuL2d2Yl3XPIJgP4E88LA39+rl8zk abhiupd1@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|         o*B.    |
|       o=++o+    |
|       .B*o      |
|       .o@oo     |
|       .S.*.+  o |
|        .  +.o..o|
|       . . .oo. .|
|      o * o.o. E.|
|       B.o.. .oo.|
+----[SHA256]-----+

**Note: This is not a ssh key which you required for your hosting service(eg. github or bitbucket) your ssh key saved in .ssh/id_rsa.pub**

**Step6**: For copy your public ssh key use below command:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

**Step7**: You will get ssh key adding option from: Right top icon click--Setting--SSH and GPG keys---New SSh key.

[image]

**Step8**: Paste your ssh key like below , and title would be like "accesstoken", Select key type: "Authentication key" and you are done.

[image]

=====================================================================
**Simple trick:
paste below as press enter again and again tiill SHA-256 image comes up.**

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Now ssh key is copy in clipboard. You can use now to paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use)

After that:

`/usr/bin/ssh-add -K` 
(add to keychain)

Source: https://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/step-by-step-ssh-on-osx-ubuntu-and-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate SSH keys (for git) in OSX by following these steps on GitHub:
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys.

If you need to stick with the .ppk key (and Luchini's post doesn't work for you), you might also find this helpful:
[Use PPK file in Mac Terminal to connect to remote connection over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475069/use-ppk-file-in-mac-terminal-to-connect-to-remote-connection-over-ssh)