# How to clone mercurial repository via ssh on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, mercurial, ssh-keys

I have a .ppk file. I put it to the .ssh folder, but when I try to clone, the server prompts for a password.

I did it on OS X. I convert .ppk to .pem. The result was the same. After that I generate key on my machine. Public key was added to the server. Nothing has changed.

I used command: `hg clone ssh://user@hostname localpackage`

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host shortname
    Hostname hostname
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyname
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the key into the openSSH format to work with `ssh`. The PKK format is format for PuTTY.

Use PuTTYgen to convert to openSSH format:

```
puttygen ~/.ssh/keyname -O private-openssh -o ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You need to install `putty` before:

```
sudo port install putty
```

<sup>[Source Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/726821/429987) | [Source SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3932540/2196426)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

But I don't understand why? When I converted it on windows in puttygen and transfer to the mac, it doesn't work.

Comment: You probably copied it over with wrong permissions or something. You would find from verbose log of `ssh -vvv user@hostname true`